# iOS - Custom section header bounds issue

Tags: ios, cgrect, uitableview

I'm trying to create my own section header for my grouped cells.  When I create it, using the following code, it looks as if the bounds are off.  More specifically the height of the `CGRect`

[image]

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *header = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 50)] autorelease];
    [header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width, 18)] autorelease];
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    label.text = @"SOME TEXT";
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [header addSubview:label];

    return header;
}
```

Any idea why the height is off? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you also implemented `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` as described in the docs? This should return 50 for your table.

Comment: Exactly what I was missing.  Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

Just curious as to why you aren't defining the TableView type (Grouped), setting the properties of the section headers in IB and then using:

```
- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: I was actually using this method before, however I couldn't get the text color to change.